# Javascript destructuring to populate existing object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm using the [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) syntax of ES6.
I want to use it in order to populate an existing object.

I got two objects:

```
let $scope = {};
let email = { from: 'cyril@so.com', to: 'you@so.com', ... };
```

I want to assign some `email` object properties to the `$scope` object.

For now, I've end up doing so:

```
({ from: $scope.from, to: $scope.to } = email);
```

In my real life use case I have more than two properties to be assigned.

So, do you know an other way to **improve** and **avoid repeating** the `$scope` in the left assignation part?

Comment: Uh, oh! Posting my question just made me though about the `Object.assign()` method..
I guess that doing ```$scope = Object.assign($scope, email);``` should do the trick.
Well, well, well, posting a question is always useful, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you can do this:

```
Object.assign($scope, email);
```

However that is not immutable, you are actually altering the $scope object (which is fine in your case). If you want an immutable operation do this:

```
$scope = Object.assign({}, $scope, email);
```

That will return a brand new object.

Also, if you have the [Object Rest Spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) feature turned on in your transpiler, then you can do this:

```
$scope = { ...$scope, ...email };
```

This is also immutable and uses `Object.assign` behind the scenes.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't though about the Object Rest Spread in this case. I'll stick to the Object.assign, still more 'human readable' I guess.
Thanks for your answer!